# I have created a mobile app with Adobe Air 3.2., but its not working on iOS 6 iPad

Tags: actionscript-3, ipad, air, flashdevelop, mobile-application

I have created a mobile app with Adobe Air 3.2., but its not working on iOS 6 iPad,

Even i Cant Install On Ipad.

please let me know how can i resolve this issue

Comment: My first attempt to solve that issue would be to use AIR 3.4 instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't install"?

Comment: @ Al_Birdy

i am tired to create app with 3.4 but my app is still not install in my ios6 ipad its work nicely in iOS 5.1 ipad si please solve this issue

@32bitkid I mean i cant install .ipa file on ipad i get some error like "my app name failed to install."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 3.2 will be supported on iOS 6. You'll need to use at a minimum 3.3 though I believe there are some issues with it as well.

Best advice is to upgrade to the most recent release ([AIR SDK here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html)) and use that, which as at writing is 3.4.0.2540. There have been a lot of mobile improvements in the latest releases [see here for a list](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/flashplayer-air-feature-list.html).

Comment: i am tired to create app with 3.4 but my app is still not install in my ios6 ipad

its work nicely in iOS 5.1 ipad si please solve this issue

Comment: Have you tried a simple application with not much code in it? Try to determine if it's something with your code or with the process.

Comment: hello
ok thanks for the reply and for helping us .
we have solve the issue to make a new certificate and remove from the ipd ios 5.1 and 6.0 version certificate you have to remove and once again you have make the certificate and provisioning profile and you have make ipa and install once again.
AIR 3.4 SDK is work nicely in iOS 6.
its really work  Have enjoy
love you adobe :)